# How to correctly launch an EMR cluster that uses Spark, via Java SDK (command-runner.jar vs directly referencing the JAR path)

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, jar, amazon-emr

If I'm trying to run a spark job on EMR using the SDK for Java, which approach is more correct? I've seen both approaches, but currently both break for me, so I'm not sure which one is the approach to take when it comes to creating a `HadoopJarStepConfig`.

**Using command-runner.jar** (as done in these two examples:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html

and

https://www.javatips.net/api/dl4j-examples-master/dl4j-spark-examples/dl4j-spark/src/main/java/org/deeplearning4j/emr/EmrSparkExample.java)

```
HadoopJarStepConfig runExampleConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
        .withJar("command-runner.jar")
        .withArgs(
            "spark-submit",
            "--master", "yarn",
            "--deploy-mode", "cluster",
            "--driver-class-path", JAR_LOCATION,  // unsure if this helps
            "--class", MAIN_CLASS,
            JAR_LOCATION,
            "-useSparkLocal", "false"
        );
```

**Without command-runner.jar** (as done here: https://sysadmins.co.za/aws-create-emr-cluster-with-java-sdk-examples/)

```
 HadoopJarStepConfig runExampleConfig = new HadoopJarStepConfig()
        .withJar(JAR_LOCATION)
        .withMainClass(MAIN_CLASS);
```

In both cases, I create a `RunJobFlowRequest` with release label `emr-5.15.0`, a Spark `Application`, and other settings that aren't relevant to the question. Furthermore, the JAR is stored in an S3 bucket.

---

For context, the first approach results in my JAR being skipped for some reason (detailed here [Trying to run Spark on EMR using the AWS SDK for Java, but it skips the remote JAR stored on S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51391911/trying-to-run-spark-on-emr-using-the-aws-sdk-for-java-but-it-skips-the-remote-j)); the second approach results in a ClassNotFoundException for org.apache.spark.SomeClass. I'm thinking it might have to do with the fact that my JAR is a super/uber JAR, and I'm not shading anything...

Comment: Turns out command-runner is the way to go, I think. I realized the JAR on S3 was being skipped because apparently it refuses to take JARs from S3 (but I'm almost certain it should be able to?), so my current workaround is to scp the JAR from my local workspace to the master node.

Comment: by chance do you remember where to download the command-runner.jar? I know EMR includes on the PATH, but in my case, I don't have access to it since I'm using the AWS Sagemaker Pyspark SDK and the full EMR config is abstracted away from me.